# Android getExtra() always gets default value in service

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am making an alarm, and service is started by the alarm. I want services to receive Extra data so with googling I set the flag as Intent.FILL_IN_DATA. Below is my code.(Only important part is shown)
(I have several alarm mode, and different services are called)

```
public static void setAlarm(Context mContext, int mode){
    if(mode==A){
                intent = new Intent(mContext, AService.class);
            }
            else{
                intent = new Intent(mContext, BService.class);
                intent.putExtra(NOTI_MODE, mode);
            }
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Log.d("set alarm","alarm 4.4");
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),    pIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d("set alarm","alarm 4.4 under");
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        }
}
public static void cancelAlarm(Context mContext){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, AService.class),Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);

        pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, BService.class),Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
```

}

service side code(edit: this code is in BService class. AService does not need to receive Extras.)

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int notiMode=intent.getIntExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.NOTI_MODE, -1);
}
```

However, the result is always -1, which means no Extras is being received.

What is the problem with my code? I'm googling for hours and no hope.

Please help if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: setAlarm method is in

public class AlarmManagerHelper extends BroadcastReceiver{} class.

and below is from AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.test.AlarmManagerHelper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

When I use

pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, BService.class), 0);

instead of

pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, BService.class),Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

at cancelAlarm(), service gets Extras all right (but the alarm does not cancel of course)

I don't get why setAlarm() does not work when I change cancelAlarm()..

Comment: Can share the class definition that contains your public static void setAlarm method?

Comment: I added the class information, but I'm not sure that is what you meant. (Actually I'm not a native speaker in English and I'm not sure what 'class definition' means..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Quite embarrassing.. I should have searched more for myself before posting the question...

Changed Intent.FILL_IN_DATA to PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and now it works like charm.

Does not know why, but if you are suffering from same problem, please try this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted, you have two services (AService and BService).

I am guessing that the code snippet you are sharing is for your AService?

I think the top part of your setAlarm method should be:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context mContext, int mode)
{
    if(mode==A)
    {
        intent = new Intent(mContext, AService.class);

        // NOTE: Add this line!
        intent.putExtra(NOTI_MODE, mode);
    }
    else
    {
        intent = new Intent(mContext, BService.class);
        intent.putExtra(NOTI_MODE, mode);
    }

    // snipped rest of code in this method
}
```

Comment: Sorry for providing insufficient information. The snippet is from BService. AService does not need to get extras. I will edit my question